# Docker build cannot find javascript modules (Docker/Nodejs/Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express

I'm building Express using Docker.

Previously, I uploaded it to the Ubuntu server using the Dockerfile.
But suddenly there was an error.
When building Docker Image, there was an error that could not read the file.
When I build with Docker and run, It can't find the javascript module I made.

An error occurred even if dockerfile2 was used instead of dockerfile1.

I don't know what the problem is.

I updated Docker, too.

`Docker version 20.10.8,`

---

**Error Msg**.
(when use dockerfile1)
[Error msg : Cannot find module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNXYc.png)

**Error Msg**.
(when use dockerfile2)

```
> socket_example@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node app.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './AgoraApi'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/src/audioChat/audioChannelHandler.js
- /usr/src/app/src/multiplay/rooms/GameRoom.js
- /usr/src/app/app.js
```

**docker file1**

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /
COPY  package.json ./
RUN  npm install
COPY  ./ ./
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**docker file2**

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY  package.json /usr/src/app
RUN  npm install
COPY  . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**dockerignore file**

```
.git
.gitignore

README.md
webpack.config.js
NAF-Gallery-Test.git
package-lock.json
backup
logs

node_modules
config/sql/*

!src
!util
```

**Folder Structure**

```
app.js
config.js
src
ㄴaudioChat
 ㄴagoraApi.js
util
ㄴvipRoomManager.js
...
```

Comment: You can try to get into running docker image and debug there. Use the command `docker exec -it docker_image_id /bin/bash`

Comment: Try that in your docker file2 `COPY  package.json .     RUN  npm install      COPY  . .` (instead of `COPY  package.json /usr/src/app` etc.)

Comment: Is there error when building or running the container?  If running, how are you launching the container (and are you replacing the `node_modules` directory from the image with unrelated content from a volume)?  Did you figure out why the first case writes out an image file instead of a text error?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you so much for your answer!! Yes, this is an error that occurs when running a docker container. Because the container was not executed, it could not be accessed by `exec -it`. Therefore, I checked the file structure through `docker cp`. But, It was the same as the local file structure. I don't know why there's an error. Is the  path the problem? 

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  You should be able to `docker run --rm -it ... your-image sh` or `docker-compose run app sh` to get an interactive debugging shell in a temporary container based on the image and look around that way.  I frequently see Node setups with Compose `volumes:` that replace the entire contents of images, and so what you're running won't really be related to the image you build.

Comment: @DavidMaze OMG... I solved it. First of all, I ran the container without using the volume. **The problem was the classification of uppercase and lowercase letters of the file name of the file...** The actual file name was `agoraApi.js`, but the file name I used was `require=(./AgoraApi.js')` When running in a local environment, there was no problem, but there was an error in the docker container. Perhaps, in a local environment, there is an automatic parsing of file names. Thank you so much for your answer. Thanks to you, I checked the file more carefully! Have a great day!